# inserting node at the end of a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am working on a code that inserts a node into the end of a linked list, and simply it does not work. It gives me that same linked list as before, without appending any nodes.

#### result

```
the old list is :
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
the new list is :
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

#### code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//make a new type structure called node
typedef struct nodes{
    int n;
    struct nodes* next;
}node;
//assigning the first node of the linked list
node* head=NULL;
//append function
void append(int number){
    node* tail=malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(tail==NULL){
        printf("unable to allocate");
        exit(1);
    }
    tail->n=number;
    tail->next=NULL;
    if(head->next==NULL){
        tail->next=head;
        printf("added successfully");
    }
    else{
        for(node* current=head;current->next==NULL;current=current->next){
            current->next=tail;
            printf("Added successfully");
            break;
        }
    }
}
//main function
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    //checking that the commmand is correct
    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Please type ./append and then type the number you want to add to the list");
    }
    //accept numbers in second argument
    int newnumber=atoi(argv[1]);
    //make the list
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        node* newnode=malloc(sizeof(node));
        //checking
        if(new==NULL){
            exit(1);
        }
        newnode->n=i;
        newnode->next=head;
        head=newnode;
    }
    //printing the old list
    printf("the old list is :\n");
    for(node* conductor=head;conductor!=NULL;conductor=conductor->next){
        printf("%i ",conductor->n);
    }
    //append the number given to the start of the linked list 
    append(newnumber);
    //printing the new list
    printf("\nthe new list is :\n");
    for(node* conductor=head;conductor!=NULL;conductor=conductor->next){
        printf("%i ",conductor->n);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

So the function seems have no impact at all. I can't see where the bug is.

Comment: You should try and avoid naming variables with `C++` keywords such as `new`. It fools the colorizer, makes the code harder to read and difficult to port to `C++`.  Also note that the initial list is constructed backwards, by prepending successive integers to the list.

Comment: I am going to fix it, I'm not familiar with C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
node* tail=malloc(sizeof(node));
```

You created a new node* called tail. It's not linked to anything yet.

First, as mentioned in the comments, your code may dereference a NULL pointer if the list is empty. You could for example add the following check at the start :

```
if(head==NULL) {
    head=tail;
    printf("Added successfully\n");
    return;
}
```

Now let's look at your code:

```
if(head->next==NULL){
        tail->next=head;
        printf("added successfully");
    }
```

Here you assign `tail->next` instead of `head->next`, so your tail is still not in the list, that's a mistake.

```
else{
        for(node* current=head;current->next==NULL;current=current->next){
            current->next=tail;
            printf("Added successfully");
            break;
        }
    }
```

And here your loop condition is wrong. That == should probably be a != for starters. Right now your loop isn't executed at all.

Then you still need to take that loop body out of the loop :

```
else {
    node* current=head;
    while (current->next!=NULL)
        current=current->next;
    current->next=tail;
    printf("Added successfully");
}
```

But really those are pretty simple mistakes, you should be able to catch them by looking carefully.

Comment: The special case `if (head->next == NULL)` is redundant.  The `while` loop you suggest will handle the case of a list with one element correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in your `append` function is bogus in both cases: if the list is empty, your test is incorrect and you only modify `tail->next` instead of `head` and if the list is not empty, you completely fail to do anything since current->next is not `NULL` at the start of the `for` loop.

Look at this corrected version:

```
void append(int number) {
    node *tail = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (tail == NULL) {
        printf("unable to allocate");
        exit(1);
    }
    tail->n = number;
    tail->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tail;
    } else {
        node *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = tail;
    }
    printf("Added successfully");
}
```